# Can I use inkjet waterslide transfers on glass bottles?

Tags: painting, glass, upcycling, decals

I was wondering if there is anyone who has used the inkjet waterslide transfers on glass or bottles as part of a recycling art project?

I will be making some wine bottles as centerpieces for my wedding and I'm wondering if I spray the bottles with acrylic paint first, could I still put the bottle in the oven to set the waterslide decals, over the paint? Or would that be disastrous?

I don't want to get it wrong as I only have a limited supply of free bottles I've been given.

Comment: The Q&A at http://www.krylon.com/products/frosted-glass-finish/ suggests not

Answer (score 2):

In scale model building, I apply waterslide decals over acrylic paint all the time.  Obviously, those models are plastic, so I don't cook them.  Instead, I put a light covering of clear coat over them after the paint has dried, then again after the decals are in-place and air-dried.

I've left uncovered decals exposed to the air without any trouble in situations where they won't be touched or handled, but whenever I want the application to be durable, a little matte clear coat does the trick.